# How do I compile a c file with native functionality to connect via JNI?

Tags: java, gcc, java-native-interface, native-code

I followed examples from java.sun.com to build sample jni app, but I've got problems. I intend to use unix with gcc. How do I compile *.c file with native function to have library? What parameters would I use? There are plenty of and I'm confused.

Comment: I'm sorry: I misread  your question. I assumed you were looking for information held in a JNI tutorial rather than a C compiler's parameters. Down-vote removed and up-vote given. I also added the GCC tag, partly because it is related to GCC but mostly so I could edit your post and be able to then change my vote. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following makefile to compile.
Just type `make` from the command line.

```
TARGET = myagent
CC = gcc

# linux config
JDK = /usr/local/share/jdk1.6.0_20
CFLAGS=-Wall -I$(IDIR) -shared -DLINUX -I$(JDK)/include/linux -I$(JDK)/include


COMPILE = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c
OBJDIR = obj
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
DEPS := $(wildcard *.h)
OBJFILES := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES)))

exe: $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(OBJFILES) -shared -o $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c $(DEPS)
$(COMPILE) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: I should put this in folder with my project? And name it 'makefile'?

Comment: I've got foollowing error: user@user:~/jni/hello$ make
makefile:16: *** missing separator.  Stop.